# Second $project Stage Producing Unexpected Result in MongoDB Aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am trying to run some aggregation in my MongoDB backend where I calculate a value and then add that calculated value to another value. The first step is working, but the second step produces a value of `null`, and I'm trying to understand why, and how to fix it.

This is what my aggregation look like:

```
db.staff.aggregate({
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      "workloadSatisfactionScore": {
          $cond: [ { $eq: [ "$workload.shiftAvg", 0 ] }, "N/A", { $divide: [ "$workload.shiftAvg", "$workload.weeklyShiftRequest.minimum" ] } ]
      }
    },
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      totalScore: {
        $sum: [ "$workloadSatisfactionScore", 10 ]
      },
    }
})
```

Even though the first `$project` stage produces documents with a numeric result or `null` for 'workloadSatisfactionScore', after the second `$project` stage, ALL documents have a value of `null` for 'totalScore'.

What I should get is whatever the value of 'workloadSatisfactionScore' is, added to 10. But as I say, all I get is `null` for all documents. What looks incorrect here?

As an example, one particular document in my collection returns a value of `0.9166666666666666` for "workloadSatisfactionScore". So when that is plugged into the second `$project` stage I'd expect a value of `10.9166666666666666` for 'totalScore'. But, as I say, instead I get `null` for that document, and all other documents.

Comment: Did you try `totalScore: { $add: [ "$workloadSatisfactionScore", 10 ] }` instead of `$sum`?

Comment: Yes I did. Same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that by the time the second `$project` pipeline is reached, `workloadSatisfactionScore` could be a string i.e. with the value `"N/A"` which will result in null when `$add` or `$sum` is used with a non-numerical value.

No need for the second project pipeline, you can add the value in the other conditional which handles the non-numerical part without passing it down the pipeline:

```
db.staff.aggregate({
    "$project": {
        "_id": 1,
        "totalScore": {
            "$cond": [ 
                { "$eq": [ "$workload.shiftAvg", 0 ] }, 
                "N/A",
                { "$add":  [
                    10,
                    { "$divide": [ 
                        "$workload.shiftAvg", 
                        "$workload.weeklyShiftRequest.minimum" 
                    ] }
                ] }
            ]
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: That works! Many thanks, @chridam. And this is more succinct. That said -- just curious -- is there any reason why the first example doesn't work - in principal?

Comment: Edited my answer to include a possible reason